# Mysql Dump Taking longer time

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, mysqldump

Mysql Dump Taking longer time

I have 188 databases, which I am individually dumping in a loop using a shell script as below

```
 echo "$(date  +%b-%d-%y) Dumping Started at $(date +%r)" | tee -a $DEST/general.logs $DEST/details.logs
for db in $databases; do
        echo "START : Dumping $db start at $(date +%r)" >> $DEST/details.logs
        if [[ "$db" != "information_schema" && "$db" != "performance_schema" ]]; then
                if ( mysqldump -u $USER -p$PASSWORD --databases $db > $DEST/$DATE.$db.sql) then
                        gzip $DEST/$DATE.$db.sql
                        echo "SUCCESS : Dumping $db" >> $DEST/details.logs
                        echo "FINISH : Dumping $db finished at $(date +%r)" >> $DEST/details.logs
                else
                        echo "FAILED : Dumping $db" | tee -a $DEST/general.logs $DEST/details.logs
                fi
        fi
done
echo "$(date  +%b-%d-%y) Dumping Finished at $(date +%r)" | tee -a $DEST/general.logs $DEST/details.logs

if [ -d "$oldBackup" ]; then
        rm -rf $oldBackup
        echo "Backup for $fiveDaysAgo removed successfully at $(date +%r)" | tee -a $DEST/general.logs $DEST/details.logs
else
        echo "Backup for $fiveDaysAgo not found." | tee -a $DEST/general.logs $DEST/details.logs
fi
echo "Backup Size" $(du -ch $DEST | grep total) >> $DEST/general.logs
```

The total size of all the databases is nearly 150GB When I restart mysql it takes nearly 2-3 hours to complete all the backups for a couple of days and then it keeps on increasing. Over a period of a week it reaches 7-8 hours and then 15 -20 Hours.

I have made sure that there is no process running while the backup is going for the first 4 hours.

Below is my sys config : OS : Centos 5.6 Mysql : 5.6 RAM : 64GB(8 cores)

Below my SQL config(my.cnf)

```
[mysqld]
#innodb_force_recovery=6
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
tmpdir=/var/lib/mysql/tmp
user=mysql

interactive_timeout=15
wait_timeout=40

symbolic-links=0
local-infile=0
port=33060
skip-name-resolve

sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp=1

innodb_buffer_pool_size=32G
innodb_log_file_size=10G
innodb_log_buffer_size=16M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
innodb_checksum_algorithm=crc32

innodb_buffer_pool_instances=8
innodb_thread_concurrency=16
innodb_lock_wait_timeout=180

innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown=1
innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup=1
innodb_io_capacity=2000
innodb_io_capacity_max=3000
innodb_lru_scan_depth=2000

#Binary log/replication
#log-bin
#sync_binlog=1
#sync_relay_log=1
#relay-log-info-repository=TABLE
#master-info-repository=TABLE
#expire_logs_days=6
#binlog_format=ROW
#transaction-isolation=READ-COMMITTED
#innodb_autoinc_lock_mode = 2
join_buffer_size=6M
sort_buffer_size=6M
read_buffer_size=6M
read_rnd_buffer_size=1M

key_buffer_size=512M
query_cache_type=0
query_cache_size=0
#query_cache_limit=1M

tmp_table_size=256M
max_heap_table_size=256M
table_open_cache_instances=16
table_open_cache=200000
table_definition_cache=100000
open_files_limit=1024000

thread_cache_size=200
max_connections=400
max_user_connections=350
max_connect_errors=99

connect_timeout=20
max_allowed_packet=128M

slow_query_log=1
long_query_time=5
slow_query_log_file=/var/log/mysql-slow.log

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet=1G
```

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @mustaccio I would like to stop this incremental increase of the backup time. Whenever I restart my server it comes down to the base time, but then again it starts increasing.

Comment: what is the output of the following two quires `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty';` and `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Innodb_page_size';`

Comment: Output of SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty' is

Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty - 1627

And of  Innodb_page_size is

 Innodb_page_size - 16384

Comment: Are all of your table InnoDB?

Comment: have you considered archiving some of your data ? this will reduce backup time and it will also improve performance of your database.

Answer (score 1):

Not a solution, but an improvement:

```
mysqldump ... | gzip >$DEST/$DATE.$db.sql.gz
```

This would avoid the I/O due to the write and reread of the `.sql` file.

You could also consider having N connections -- N-1 doing the biggest databases, 1 doing all the rest.  N=4 might be reasonable; there is no use making it too high -- once the I/O is saturated, no further speedup can be had.

A minor note:  Since you are invoking `date` more than once, there is a chance of getting a different value somewhere in the middle of the script.  Recommend capturing it in a variable.

Does the `du` show a significant difference from one time to the next?